# Apache Solr slow search

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, solrj

I am struggling with solr to make a better search than current implementation on my code.
The current code looks into some caches/hashmaps  to retrieve data and what I want to do is to optimize the query response time.
So I already indexed 2 version of documents (some simple documents which does not contain othe objects inside them.only strings and ints). and everything works great.

But now I'm facing another problem while I'm trying to index another core for a more complex bean.

I have a bean like:

```
Public class Person{
   String name;
   String surname;
   List<Adresse> adress;
   List<Stuff> stuff;
   List<HashMap<String,String>> otherStuff;
}
```

Solr helped me only by mapping the simple Lists and  the List of Maps, so I mannualy mapped the remaining members (Lists) by transforming from object to List of strings and viceversa from string to Object and set the value into current obtaining object.
But this approach caused really slow response times for my queries.

I am also facing another problem.The execution times gets very slow while I'm receiving more that 10 documents from the index.

Can you guys please help me with suggestions/ideas on how to make all this faster ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very complex structure, you might be better off not trying to get it back from Solr. Instead, have the field definitions with *stored=false* and just get back IDs. Then, round-trip to your original source to get the actual objects.

Then, Solr because just the way to search and you can skip sending any fields to it that you are not searching against.